# How would I use Tidyverse to improve my assign, do.call, and for loop code?

Tags: r

I haven't done any R coding for years.  I am retired and a simple hobbyist programmer; so when I code I rely on "brute force", old fashioned procedural code.

I have a small amount of code that works for what I want.  However, compared to what I see these days, it is clunky and ugly.  I am hoping someone will be kind enough to offer suggestions for updating this code.

I am using the nflscrapR package to access data for personal, hobby purposes (e.g., tracking which QB is scrambling for his life these days? How often? And compared to who else?).

The example code below uses game id data to access game summary data (but my real interest is the play by play data).  I create dataframe variable names from the game ids, download the data, save it to the dataframe, then write that data to a .csv file, and finally merge those files into a single weekly file.  (I manually set the "k" variable once a week, change directories a couple of times in the code and my file naming is ugly.)  I am most interested in improved creation and assignment of variables and more parsimonious "looping".

```
######  Weekly game summary script  #######
library(nflscrapR)
k <- 3

setwd("./nflscrapeR/GameIDs/2018 Game IDs")
gameID.File <- read.csv(file = paste("2018 Week ", k, " GameIDs.csv", sep = ""))
gameID.list <- gameID.File$game_id
res <- paste0("ds", gameID.list, sep = "")

setwd(paste("./nflscrapeR/GameSummary/Week ", k, sep = ""))

for(i in 1:length(res)){
  write.csv(assign(res[[i]],drive_summary(gameID.list[[i]])), file = paste(res[[i]], ".csv", sep = ""), row.names = FALSE)
}

file_names <- dir()
weeklysummary <- do.call(rbind,lapply(file_names,read.csv))
setwd("./nflscrapeR/GameSummary")
write.csv(weeklysummary, file = paste("week", k, "summaries_2018.csv", sep = ""), row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: The `purrr` package is great for this sort of thing. Similar example here: https://serialmentor.com/blog/2016/6/13/reading-and-combining-many-tidy-data-files-in-R

Comment: Thanks.  This is exactly the type of pointer I was looking for.